# Asana API - Setting the commenting user and html tags

Tags: html, api, comments, asana, userid

I'm creating tasks in Asana via the api and pulling comments from elsewhere into Asana 'stories'. This all works well however the api doesn't seem to allow a user id to be passed for the comment - so it appears that only I have made comments and am answering myself!

I am wondering if there is a hidden bit of the api to set the commenting user id?

Also the body of the comment displays html tags such as

```
<li> <ol> <br>
```

as plain text. Is there a way to fix this also?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story should [have a field](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#stories) called `created_by` which is a struct that contains the user id and user name. Is this always you?

If you're using the API to add a comment, then the creating user will always be you. There API provides no way to impersonate another user. Unless you can get their API credentials, this is a no go.

As for stripping the text - sadly, no. There is no way to prevent this.